# What rules govern group skill checks?

Tags: dnd-4e, skills, group-checks

A number of published adventures mention rolling a "group stealth check" and other group checks where, theoretically, a proportion of the players try to beat the DC.

Are there formal rules for this, and if so, where?

Comment: Which adventurers is this found in?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*[Rules Compendium](http://www.wizards.com/dnd/Product.aspx?x=dnd/products/dndacc/247530000)* page 128 states that group checks are almost always against an easy DC and if at least half the group succeeds the whole group succeeds. Otherwise the group fails.

Comment: Rules Compendium? Is there a link to this thing? Is this duplicated in the DMG or someplace? I'm surprised  - do I need to buy yet-another rulebook?

Comment: The Rules Compendium came out with the Essentials line launch. And is probably one of the most useful books (if not the) to have at the table.

Answer (score 5):

DMG1, p.75

Real mechanic.

> **Group Skill Checks**
>   Sometimes a skill challenge calls for a group skill
>   check. When the party is climbing a cliff, everyone
>   needs to roll an Athletics check to climb. In this
>   case, allow one character to be the lead climber. This
>   character makes the actual check to gain a success or
>   failure. The others make checks to help the lead character,
>   in effect aiding that character, but their checks
>   provide neither a success nor a failure toward resolving
>   the challenge. Each ally that gets a result of 10
>   or higher provides a +2 bonus to the lead character’s
>   check (to a maximum bonus of +8).

Comment: That's been updated (superseded) by DMG2 page 83, which is also in the Compendium.